# How to set UIDatePicker only for months

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Is it possible to show only months in `UIDatePicker` list?

```
@IBOutlet weak var monthsTextField: UITextField!
private var datePicker : UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageViewController.dateChanged(datePicker: )), for: .valueChanged)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomePageViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        monthsTextField.inputView = datePicker
}



@objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMMMd"
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMM")

        monthsTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        //view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

After click on `DatePicker` on the bottom of the screen shows list with Months/Day/Year

Comment: You just want 1-12 (or Jan-Dec) and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, I need only values from January to December

Comment: I think you should use a custom `UIPickerView` instead

Comment: @TungVuDuc thank you, I thought it's possible to select only months values from `UIDatePicker`. I will change it

Answer (score 0):

`UIDatePicker` does not support a mode that shows just months. And such a result won't give you a `Date`. All you know is a month name or number.

To do what you want, you need to use `UIPickerView`. Setup the picker view's data source to use the array of month names obtained from:

```
let monthNames = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).monthSymbols
```